# File not Found in Pascal (Reset function)

Tags: input, pascal

I have a problem with reading text from .txt file using Pascal. When I try to run the code I get an EXITCODE = 2 (File not Found). It crashes on the Reset function.

```
var
  name: string;
  c: char;
  f: text;

begin
   name := 'config.txt';
   assign(f,name);
   reset(f);
   while not eof(f) do begin
     read(f,c);
     write(c)
   end
end.
```

If I provide complete address to file it works as expected. The problem arises when the address is relative (as shown).

Both the code and the text file are in the same directory.

I use FreePascal Compiler version 2.6.4

Comment: I can't reproduce this, using your exact code, with a file named `config.txt` in the same folder as the executable. (I copied and pasted your exact code, added the missing `program testread; uses SysUtils;` at the beginning, and saved it as `testread.dpr`, and then compiled it from the command line using Delphi, and then from that same command prompt ran `testread.exe`.) Are you sure your .exe is in the same folder as the text file?

Comment: I have added the lines 'program testread; uses SysUtils;'. Now when I run the code in FPC it exits with EXITCODE = 217 but if I just execute the testread.exe in the folder it works correctly.

Comment: Error code 217 is Control-C (EControlC). The code you've posted should not be generating that error, so there's got to be more code than what you've posted here. What OS are you using? Are you creating a console application?

Comment: Set the "run in" directory to your directory. EXE localtion is not necessarily the exe's working dir.

Comment: I have added readln() at the end to see the results but apart from that I did not add anything.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Wonderful. It was running in FPC directory, instead of the directory it was saved in. Now it runs correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said @Marco van de Voort in comments the problem was in FPC running the .exe in its default directory instead of the directory it was saved in.

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem, you could do something like this (you'll need to add SysUtils to your Uses clause):

```
CurrentPath := GetCurrentDirectory;
If DirectoryExists(CurrentPath) And FileExists('config.txt') Then...
```

That will make sure that you're in the same path as the executable and make sure that the file 'config.txt' is actually there in the same directory.  This is what I use under both Linux and Windows to verify if a file exists in a directory.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Enable this:

```
Options -> Enviroment -> Preferences -> [Options] Change dir on open
```

... and be happy ;)

/* Actual for [Turbo Pascal 7.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/turbopascal7/)  */